# Why cpp diagnostics and code completion stopped working in RStudio?

Tags: clang, rstudio, rcpp

I have been using Rcpp and RcppArmadillo for quite some time now and I love it! The feasibility of my research projects was boosted thanks to much faster computation performed using cpp code in R!

A super useful functionality of Rcpp is script diagnostics and code completion understood as in this doc: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-the-RStudio-IDE

It was working well in my RStudio until it stopped. Now whatever I do, I can't bring this functionality back. And I'm not that happy about it.

Do you have a solution to that? I could not find anything really here. I would greatly appreciate your help.

I work on mac with the latest system updates. I have up-to-date versions of RStudio, R, XCode, and freshly reinstalled Rcpp and RcppArmadillo packages. The compiler and the codes work perfectly fine. Just not the extra RStudio functionality with cpp. I'd be happy to provide more info about my setup if required.

Comment: Paging @kevin-ushey to see if he has an idea.

Comment: Thank you @DirkEddelbuettel I have already solved the problem following the recommendation for the clang diagnostics below!

Comment: Great, and yes, that was due to me poking JJ and Kevin over on the Rcpp slack :)  And feel free to upvote it too (besides accepting) as I happen to know who gave the one upvote so far ...

Comment: Yes, I will upvote once I get enough reputation points that will let me do so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute `.rs.setClangDiagnostics(2)` from the R console before you interact w/ C++ you should see some detailed error messages in the console indicating what the source of the problem might be. I am a bit out of practice interpreting these diagnostics but @kevin-ushey or someone else on the RStudio team should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Thanks so much @jjallaire! This worked! The outcome was:

`
> .rs.setClangDiagnostics(2)
Attemping to load libclang for x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 
/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/rsclang/libclang.dylib
   (Not Found)
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libclang.dylib
   (Not Found)
`

Comment: So, I installed XCode Command Line Tools and everything started working perfectly fine back again! Thanks again!

Your answer was useful because: (i) I did not know one can have XCode but not CLT, (ii) I did not know that CLT is related to this functionality, (iii) I did not know that this type of clang diagnostics can be performed.

I have some IT background but I am predominantly an econometrician. Very grateful for your help :)